# jQuery Fancybox and pass of variables

Tags: forms, post, fancybox

I have the following html markup

```
<form id="form" action="javascript:parent.$.fancybox.open({href : 'reserva.php?funcio=ryry', type: 'iframe'});" method="post">
```

...etc..

This opens a fancybox window from a post form.

How can I pass variables from my form to my iframe fancybox?

Comment: I would rather create the function to catch inline parameters from the URL inside reserva.php. In other words, if you have `href="reserva.php?function=ryry&param1=value1&param2=value2"` then read from inside reserva.php the values of those parameters -OR- submit the form via ajax and pass the variables as data.

Comment: Ye, its works. This is a good solution

Comment: If you have found a solution to your problem. Please post it as an answer and accept it. This will help other people solve similar problems.